# Espaço desnecessário na div do módulo de vendas

Tags: php, magento, div, css-display

[image: SS]

Eu tenho uma pergunta pra vocês. Meu problema é que o espaço na exibição é muito grande se eu escondo as mesmas opções no carrinho de compras!

Meu código esconde a imagem do produto mas o espaço em branco (vazio) é grande. Eu quero consertar isso para ter um leiaute bonito.

```
/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customcart/cart/item/default.phtml [o arquivo original]
```

CÓDIGO:

```php
<td class="product-cart-image">
    <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?>
    <?php //hide product link of image only ?>
        <?php if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('....../option/rwd_item_image')): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image">
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif;?>
        <?php //hide product image only ?>
        <?php if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('...../option/rwd_item_image')): ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(180); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?>
        </a>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Esse código esconde a imagem e o link do produto no carrinho. Mas é difícil de reduzir o espaço vazio. Eu quero remover o espaço vazio, como eu faço isso?

Comment: Amigo, aqui todo mundo fala português. Então, poderia por favor editar a sua pergunta para traduzi-la?

Comment: Eu mandei uma edição de tradução.

Answer (score 1):

Esta é uma dica muito útil e que muitos novatos se batem para realizar: habilitar os template hints no admin do Magento.

Para tanto, basta executar o seguinte comando SQL em seu banco de dados:

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value)
VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints', 1),
('default', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints_blocks', 1);
```

E agora, claro, como desabilitar:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 0 WHERE 
(scope = 'default' AND scope_id = 0 AND path = 'dev/debug/template_hints') OR
(scope = 'default' AND scope_id = 0 AND path = 'dev/debug/template_hints_blocks')
```

Com isso você consegue visualizar aonde esta gerando o espaço desnecessário.